# Delete comment popup temporarily unresponsive

Tags: bug, design, comments, deleted-comments

The "delete my comment: confirm / cancel" popup is always unresponsive for several seconds.

Anyone else experiencing this, and any way to fix it?

**Cases:**

1. Yes on PC, Windows 10 Enterprise, x64, so far whatever the browser and network:

   - up to date Chrome browser

     - behind proxy at work
     - with home wi-fi
     - from mobile hotspot
   - Edge browser

     - tested: behind proxy at work
2. No: on Android mobile with Firefox

**Unresponsive how:**

- I am using the mouse.
- The popup appears normally after clicking "delete".
- Except that clicking "OK" has no effect for a while: the popup usually sticks for a couple seconds, up to ten seconds once, until finally another click on "ok" is able to trigger the expected response (both popup and comment disappear).

It really is no big deal, of course. It is just surprising. My PC is in good state of maintenance and not slow in any way.

Comment: Always unresponsive where? Did you try on different computers/networks? Did you check the developer tools of your browser to see if there are any errors in the javascript console or the network tab? Are you on an up to date browser?

Comment: So you can't reproduce it yourself on a different device. Makes the machine it is happening on kind of suspicious, right? Try in a different browser at least to see if it can be reproduced there. If you can't reproduce it there either... we have found the culprit. Something in the browser itself.

Comment: All right and I'll add at least a second PC to the survey over the weekend.

Comment: Not a second PC, use the same with a different browser.

Comment: 1) By "Chrome navigator", did you mean "Chrome browser"? Or is it a different thing, e.g. browser extension? 2) How did you navigate the popup? With a mouse or keyboard? 3) If possible, could you explain more specifically what is "unresponsive"?

Comment: @AndrewT. Chrome browser, yes. navigation with mouse. updating post

Comment: I have the [same problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426796/8681), on both my home PC (Windows 10, Chrome) and work laptop (Ubuntu 22.04, Chrome).

Comment: @Jorn ok, this bring a second machine to the panel, unfortunately I guess. Both Windows 10.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that this bug still happens occasionally. And whenever it does, I open the browser console to find out why, click the OK button one more time to reproduce, and then it works. So I still can't offer any useful debug data, unfortunately.