# I can't delete my own comments sometimes

Tags: bug, comments

Lately, I've ran into a bug where I can click the "Delete" link on one of my own comments, and have the browser confirmation dialog come up. However, when I then click "OK", nothing happens: The button lights up, but the dialog doesn't go away and the comment isn't deleted. Sometimes refreshing the page and trying again helps, sometimes it doesn't.

I've tried checking what happens with the browser console, but both times the OK button actually worked correctly after opening it. Which is probably a coincidence, but it's weird that it happened twice.

Comment: For completeness' sake, this bug isn't consistent. It only happens some of the time.

Comment: I just deleted a comment under here, just fine... You're not getting any console errors or something else indicating a problem?

Comment: I'll keep an eye out if it happens again. As stated in the post, I already tried to use the console to check, but both times I tried the problem didn't reoccur after I opened the console.

Comment: It doesn't really answer anything, but yes, that sounds like the same problem. I should add that I've seen this problem on both my home PC (Windows 10, Chrome) and work laptop (Ubuntu 22.04, Chrome).