# Unresponsive `Edit` Button in review Queues

Tags: bug, review-queues

When you click 'Edit' in the review queues, if there are too many pending edit requests at that moment, the button remains unresponsive. Shouldn't a pop-up message be displayed to inform the user that there are too many pending requests?

Comment: This isn't the first time I read about an unresponsive button lately. There was also this one for example: [Delete comment popup temporarily unresponsive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426763/delete-comment-popup-temporarily-unresponsive).